# How do I output name of dominant color after determining the dominant colour?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, background-color, pixel

Assume that number of pixels for each colors are counted in an image.

And number of pixels are printed like following code.

```
x=np.count_nonzero(frame)
x1=np.count_nonzero(red_mask)
x2=np.count_nonzero(blue_mask)
x3=np.count_nonzero(green_mask)
x4=np.count_nonzero(orange_mask)
x5=np.count_nonzero(yellow_mask)
x6=np.count_nonzero(cyan_mask)
x7=np.count_nonzero(black_mask)
x8=np.count_nonzero(gray_mask)
x9=np.count_nonzero(white_mask)
x10=np.count_nonzero(violet_mask)
x11=np.count_nonzero(brown_mask)

print('total number of pixels in  image', x)
print('Red is ', x1)
print('Blue is', x2)
print('Green is', x3)
print('Orange is', x4)
print('Yellow is', x5)
print('Cyan is ', x6)
print('Black is', x7)
print('Gray is', x8)
print('White is', x9)
print('Violet is', x10)
print('Brown is', x11)
```

How can I output the dominant colour by calculating Maximum output value. I understand that using following script I can output number of pixels for particular dominant color, but how can I output the name of dominant color assassinated the maximum pixel number?

```
zz=max(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11)
print(zz)
```

Comment: you have a relationship between pixel number and color -so your data should reflect that. Try approaching the problem by making a dict of the form `{color --> pixel_count}` or a list of tuples of the form `[(color, pixel_count)]`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the color as key and the number as value

```
dict = {} # creates an empty dictionary
dict["Red"] = np.count_nonzero(red_mask)
# so on for the rest of the color
```

Then you can get the color with the maximum number with a for loop or using a lambda function, thanks to the comment

```
color = max(dict.keys(), key=(lambda key: dict[key])) 
print(color)
```

```
max = 0
color = ""
for key, value in dict.items():
    if(max < value):
        max = value
        color = key
print(color)
```

Comment: `color = max(dict.keys(), key=(lambda key: dict[key]))` will return the key with the greatest value

Comment: @CHaworth got it

Answer (score 2):

You can make a list of colors with the same index as your variables i.e.

```
colors = ["Red","Blue",..."Brown"]
```

Then use np.argmax to find the index of the highest pixel number

```
zz=np.argmax([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11])
```

Finally, use zz as an index into your colors list

```
print(colors[zz])
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace discrete variables with a single list:

```
masks = [ frame, red_mask, blue_mask, green_mask, orange_mask, yellow_mask, cyan_mask, black_mask, gray_mask, white_mask, violet_mask, brown_mask ]
labels = [ 'total number of pixels in image', 'Red is ', 'Blue is', 'Green is', 'Orange is', 'Yellow is', 'Cyan is', 'Black is', 'Gray is', 'White is', 'Violet is', 'Brown is' ]

counts = [ np.count_nonzero(i) for i in masks ]
for c, l in zip(counts, labels):
  print(l, c)
print("Max is", colors[np.argmax(counts)])
```